# Logstash Elasticsearch Parent child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have following questions:

1. Suppose, I have 3 tables in relation database:

   `master` (contains item_id & location_id)

   `Location` (location_id and description)

   `Item_master` (item_id & description)

   `Location` and `Item_master` are parents and clearly `master` is a child.
   Can a child have two parents in Elasticsearch?

   If not, what is the workaround to show *parent child* in this case?
2. I am using *logstash* to feed data into Elasticsearch. What filter configuration do I use in *logstash* to get *parent child relationship*?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @KevinOelen : Child can't have two parents , We have created temporary table(view) in hadoop and using elasticsearch hadoop integration , we are transfering data in to single index in elastic search .